# What is difference between free and faithful group action?

Tags: group-actions

I searched Wikipedia for definitions of free and faithful actions. As I understand them, the two concepts are the same thing!

If they are one concept, what is the point of introducing both or even of naming them in distinct ways?

Comment: What wiki? On the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Types_of_actions), the definitions are clearly different (free implies faithful, but not the other way round).

Comment: They are actually different concepts. "Faithful" means that there is no kernel (i.e, no element different from the identity fixes all elements of your set), whereas "free" means that the action of any element different from the identity is fixed-point free.

Comment: Free means 
$$\forall g \in G \;[\exists x \in X, g x = x \implies g = 1]$$

Faithful means
$$\forall g \in G \;[\forall x \in X, g x = x \implies g = 1]$$

Answer (score 26):

Free mean that if there is $x \in X$ and $g,h$ with $gx = hx$ then $g = h$. Faithful means that the morphism $G \to Sym(X)$ induced by the action is injective, i.e for all $g\ne h$ there is a $x \in X$ with $gx \neq hx$.

Of course, being free is stronger. It's not equivalent since the action of $\text{SO}(2)$ on $\Bbb R^2$ this is not free since there is a fixed point but it's faithful (take $x = (1,0)$ works for all $g,h \in \text{SO}(2)$).

Comment: thank you, i had a foolish mistake in reading their definitions!

Comment: @mja : you're welcome ! Don't hesitate to activate the little green mark next to the answer if this was useful to you :)

Comment: Is "being free" actually stronger than "being faithful"? The action $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \text{Sym}(\emptyset)$ is free but not faithful.

Answer (score 14):

As Keith Conrad explains on [his notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/%7Ekconrad/blurbs/grouptheory/gpaction.pdf):

> "It is worth comparing faithful and free actions. An action is *faithful* when ${g_1 \neq g_2  \Rightarrow  g_1 x \neq g_2 x}$ for some ${x \in X}$ (different elements of $G$ act differently at some point) while an action is *free* when ${g_1 \neq g_2 \rightarrow g_1 x \neq g_2 x}$ for all ${x \in X}$ (different elements of $G$ act differently at every point). Since ${g_1 x = g_2 x}$ if and only if $g_2^{-1} g_1 x = x$ we can describe faithful and free actions in terms of fixed points: an action is faithful when each $g \neq e$ has Fix${_g}(X) \neq X$ while an action is free when each $g \neq e$ has Fix${_g}(X) = \emptyset$."